# USB stick bootable on both Wintel and Mac hardware

Tags: dual-boot, windows, usb-drive, mac, portable

I would like to create a bootable USB stick to use as a portable Ubuntu installation that I can bring with me and run on both Wintel and Mac hardware. Is it possible to create such an installation on a USB stick?

Comment: Seems simple enough. Just follow the instructions [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

Answer (score 0):

Just use startup disk creator(linux) unetbootin(windows) to do it.
Set persistence mode on to be able to save files to it without the usb deleting your files.